# How to change default permission for usb devices filesystem

Tags: filesystems, udev, usb-drive

On Debian, when automounted, all files and directories in USB drives have 777 permissions. I don't like it very much. I know a bit of udev rules, and I think I could write a rule of mine to override the default behaviour. But I also would like to know which system rules are involved in this mechanism, can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would have though you would be making an entry in /etc/fstab for this?

Comment: fstab it's not smart enough. There's already a subsystem which manages device hot plugging, it only needs to be tweaked a bit.

Comment: First step is to find out which package you have installed that does the automounting. For example, `usbmount` allows you to specify permissions and owner/group of mounted FAT filesystems in the configuration, IIRC. And yes, it uses udev rules, so you don't have to write those yourself.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation I am seeing, you can add this to `/etc/udev/rules.d/openauto.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="*", ATTR{idProduct}=="*", MODE="0660", GROUP="plugdev"
```

Naturally, set the `MODE` and `GROUP` to your desired permission set and group-owner for your system.